# value of parameter a such that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a 3-periodic point

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Let

\begin{cases}
T_a(x) = ax & \text{ if}  &  x \in  [0; \frac{1}{2}],\\
T_a(x) = a(1 − x) & \text{ if} &  x \in  [\frac{1}{2}; 1].
\end{cases}

Find a parameter value of $a$ for which $\frac{1}{2}$ is a $3$-periodic point.

I have tried to distinguish several cases.

1. If $0  \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2a}$.
   Then $0 \leq ax \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $T_a^2(x)= T(ax)=a^2x$.
2. If $\frac{1}{2a}  \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$.
   Then $\frac{1}{2} \leq ax \leq \frac{a}{2}$ and $T_a^2(x)= T(a(1-x))=a(1-ax)$.
3. If $\frac{1}{2}  \leq x \leq \frac{a+1}{2}$.
   Then $\frac{a(a-1)}{2} \leq a(1-x) \leq \frac{a}{2}$ and $T_a^2(x)= T(a(1-x))=a^2(1-x)$.

I am confused about the manner to mimic the response as shown on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948090/techniques-for-finding-period-points?rq=1).
$$
f^{n}(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
a^nx & \text{if} & x\in\big[0,\tfrac{1}{2a^n}\big], \\
1-a^nx\big(x-\tfrac{1}{2a^n}\big) & \text{if} & x\in\big[\tfrac{1}{2a^n},\tfrac{2}{2a^n}\big], \\
a^n\big(x-\tfrac{2}{2a^n}\big) & \text{if} & x\in\big[\tfrac{2}{2a^n},\tfrac{3}{2a^n}\big], \\
& \vdots & \\
1-a^n\big(x-\tfrac{2a^n-1}{2a^n}\big) & \text{if} & x\in\big[\tfrac{2a^n-1}{2a^n},1\big],
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and why it doesn't seem to work.)

I'm assuming you're restricted to $ a \in [ 0, 2 ]$ for the function to make sense. In particular, we do not allow $a =-1.$

**Hint:** Deal with cases based on the supposed value of $ T_ a ( 0.5), T_a ( T_a (0.5) ) $.
IE Case 1: $T_ a ( 0.5) \leq 0.5 , T_a ( T_a (0.5) ) \leq 0.5$.

Show that in all cases, we require $ a = 1$.

Comment: I do not see why $a$ must to be in $[0,2]$. For example when $a=3$, for example, we can compute $T(3x)$ for $x \in [0;1/6] $.

Comment: @Furdzik With $ a = 3$, what is $ T T (0.5) $?

Comment: $T(0.5)=1.5$ but $1.5 \notin [0;1]$. So we can't compute  $TT(0.5)$.

Comment: @Furdzik That's my point exactly. Since we can't compute $TT(0.5)$, then the function cannot be 3-periodic.