# Elementary construction of a continuous function having periodic points of arbitrarily large order

Tags: analysis

I would like to know a construction of a function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ that is continuous and that has periodic points of arbitrarily large order, that is, such that for all $N$, there exists $x$ and $n$ greater than $N$ such that $f^n(x) = x$ and $f^m(x) \neq x$ for all $m < n$; the construction of $f$ and the proof that it satisfies the required properties should be elementary.

I am aware of Sharkovskii's theorem, so that any $f$ with points of odd period will satisfy this property, and there are indeed ones that are very simple (for example, $\frac{2}{7}$ is a point of period $3$ of the map $x \mapsto \min(1, 1- 2\vert x -\frac{1}{2}\vert)$, so, by Sharkovskii's theorem, this map has periodic points of arbitrary large orders). However, I do not consider that Sharkovskii's theorem is elementary enough.

Comment: "and there are indeed ones that are very simple": so, did you try to work out one directly?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948090/techniques-for-finding-period-points

Comment: @AnneBauval: Not really. I don't have any clues. I edited my question to explain what I meant.

Comment: @Gerd: Thank you, I will take a look at the answers.

Comment: "Not really":  Well, maybe you should try, and present your first attempts.

Comment: I mean, of course I could just copy the proof of Sharkovskii's theorem of this special case, simplify what can be simplified, and I am guaranteed to arrive to a trivial but very long proof of what I want. What is the point of doing so? Thanks to Gerd's link, I have clues to where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the link given by @Gerd, and could come up with the elementary answer below.

Let $f : x \mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{cc}2x &\mbox{if } x \leq \frac{1}{2}\\2 -2x&\mbox{if } x > \frac{1}{2}\\\end{array}\right.$.

Let $n$ be an integer greater than $1$. Consider $x_n := \frac{2}{2^n-1}$. Then for all $m \leq n-2$, $f^m(x_n) = \frac{2^{m+1}}{2^n-1}$. So $f^{n-2}(x_n) = \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$, $f^{n-1}(x_n) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n -1}$ and $f^n(x_n) = x_n$. This proves that $x_n$ is a periodic point of $f$ of period exactly $n$, which solves my question.